# Default resource cap on root user

Tags: security, root, ulimit

I happened to see that on my Ubuntu 12.04 some resources of the root user is capped. I have not capped anything explicitly and my limits.conf as far as root user is concerned is empty. Here is the output of the ulimit -a on the root user

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 95931
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 95931
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

So I believe it is a default capping. So my question is what is the reason behind capping these resources of the root user by default? Now when I try to set the file limit to unlimited as root user by using the below command , I get an operation not permitted error.

```
ulimit -H -n unlimited
```

What prevents me from setting the limit to infinity and how safe it is to set it to infinity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those default limits are hardcoded into the kernel source. Those limits are set for the `init` process by the kernel and other processes inherit it from `init`. See [here](https://serverfault.com/a/485277/203306).

Why you get an error when trying to set the number of open files to unlimited is likely because the system-wide setting is not unlimited, check it with`cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max`. See [here](https://superuser.com/a/325323/283334):

> file-max & file-nr:
>
> The value in file-max denotes the maximum number of file-
>   handles that the Linux kernel will allocate. When you get lots
>   of error messages about running out of file handles, you might
>   want to increase this limit.

You can change that system-wide limit if you run e.g. `echo 300000 > /proc/sys/fs/file-max` as root, or with `sysctl -w fs.file-max=300000` as root. To make those changes permanent add a line similar to the following

```
fs.file-max=300000
```

to the `/etc/sysctl.conf` file, e.g by running `echo "fs.file-max=300000" >> /etc/sysctl.conf` as root.